# Как сделать кнопку reset для очистить label в groupBox’е

Tags: c#

Есть два checkedListBox’а. При выборе элементов в checkedListBox1 они при нажатии кнопки переносятся в checkedListBox2, после чего удаляются из checkedListBox1. Также параллельно идет запись перемещаемых элементов в label groupBox1. Каждая операция записывается в отдельный label.

Необходимо создать кнопку очистки (сброса). Для checkedListBox под кнопку reset просто записал их начальные данные. А вот что прописать для label в groupBox1 или как их сбросить не понимаю.

Глобально Application.Restart(); не подходит. Окно с формой по новому перезапускается, не очень приятно для глаз

Код что у меня есть

```
int count = 1;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)             // перенос выбранных элементов из Box1 в Box2 с сохранением в Box2 
            {
                checkedListBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }

            List<string> items = new List<string>();         // добавление отмеченных элементов в label groupBox1
            foreach (var el in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                items.Add(el.ToString());
            }
            if (items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ничего не выбрано");
                return;
            }
            foreach (Control label in this.groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if (label is Label)
                {
                    if (label.Name.Substring(5).ToString() == count.ToString())
                    {
                        label.Text = String.Join(",", items);
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)  // удаление выбранных элементов из Box1
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i--]);
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: `label.Text = "";`

Comment: так сама запись label исчезает и в него больше ничего не записывается